# How switch between method signatures with arrow keys in Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I want to be able to achieve the following with Resharper:

- When I type (e.g.) "Insights.Report(" I do not want a closing parenthesis added automatically.
- Be able to cycle through the individual signatures with the arrow keys

As soon as I type the "(" I get the list of signatures but I cannot loop through them because a weird list of parameters is offered:

[image]

I do not see what is wrong in my settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought is that the intellisense prompt is taking focus from the method parameter info list.

Trying it out myself I can tap Escape to dismiss the intellisense prompt and then use the arrow keys to switch between the parameter info options.

As for not automatically populating the closing parentheses I don't know how to set that up and I don't see why you would want to either. I found the option to turn it off in VisualStudio but it seems that ReSharper is overriding it somehow.